# IE8 jQuery Invalid Argument Due To paddingRight and parseInt()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

### Question:

I'm getting an Invalid Argument Error when debugging a site of mine. The error only occurs when hovering over an accordian menu item.. After further inspection i discovered the code that could potentially be causing this and it is in my question further below. (See Update #2).

I have no idea what specifically is causing the error, or how to fix it.. HALPS

**The line of code that it highlights is:**
`a.elem.style&&a.elem.style[a.prop]!=null?a.elem.style[a.prop]=a.now+a.unit:a.elem[a.prop]=a.now`

I can't figure it out.. I hate IE8 :)

---

### Update #1

I Traced my problem to the collapsible navigation that came pre-built with this Admin Template i downloaded from ThemeForest.

**something in the code for "Accordian Menu" that i found:**

https://gist.github.com/48d7ffcc654ce24040c5

**and this bit of code to initialize the menu:**

```
/*
 * Accordion Menu
 */
$('.menu').initMenu();
```

### Update #2

Further inspection reveals IE8 Dev Tools throwing this under **Locals**:

`Prop "PaddingRight" String`

Then i stumbled on a line in the second function in the gist:

```
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    paddingLeft:parseInt(padding_left) + parseInt(5) + "px",
                    paddingRight: parseInt(padding_right) - parseInt(5) + "px"
                }, 130);
            },
            function() {
                bc_hover = $(this).css("background-color");
                $(this).animate({
                    paddingLeft: padding_left,
                    paddingRight: padding_right
                }, 130);
            }
```

### Update #3

Here is a jsfiddle of the code with something i tried, and in jsfiddle i can't replicate the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/7Y68Y/6/

Comment: If you can't replicate the problem with the Accordian Menu with a jsFiddle, then it's a good change the script is sound for IE8. Perchance something else is affecting the Menu's Layout. Do you have a test page to look at?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't see any errors using IE7 or even in Quirks mode. Something else is the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of error is common when meddling with CSS. If a CSS property is given a wrong value, IE will complain about it.

**Update**

The OP forgot to mention that `padding_left` is declared earlier as `$(this).css('padding-left')`

In that case, you should be aware of empty strings; for instance:

```
$('<div />').css('padding-left') == ''
parseInt('') == NaN
```

With that knowledge, let's change the assignments:

```
var padding_left = $(this).css("padding-left");
var padding_right = $(this).css("padding-right");
```

To turn them into proper integers:

```
var padding_left = parseInt($(this).css('padding-left') || 0);
var padding_right = parseInt($(this).css("padding-right") || 0);
```

Then let's go back to the animation code:

```
$(this).animate({
    paddingLeft: parseInt(padding_left) + parseInt(5) + "px",
    paddingRight: parseInt(padding_right) - parseInt(5) + "px"
}, 130);
```

Let's assume the original padding was also in `px` units. In that case we can simplify the statement to:

```
$(this).animate({
    paddingLeft: (padding_left + 5) + "px",
    paddingRight: (padding_right - 5) + "px"
}, 130);
```

And the other:

```
$(this).animate({
    paddingLeft: padding_left + "px",
    paddingRight: padding_right + "px"
}, 130);
```

Comment: @arttronics SO is not a link harbor, answers are given based on the posted question.

Comment: @arttronics in any case, the answer is updated to reflect the newly acquired knowledge

Comment: Ok Jack, but it's not his code. And it works without error in IE8. This SO Question, the complete question, is based on the assumption the Accordion Menu is defective, which is isn't. Waiting to hear from the OP.

Comment: @arttronics To me it doesn't matter where the error is as I'm merely highlighting a potential issue with the code already earmarked by the OP